# Angular Material md-grid-list overlaps on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, html, css, material-design, angular-material

I am working on a angular material application. i have a page where i need to list number of languages. i am using md-grid-list instead of conventional ul and li.
However when the page loads/refreshes the list gets overlapped for a fraction of second before it gets displayed properly.

[image]

**Code**

```
  <md-grid-list md-cols-md="3" md-cols-lg="3" md-cols-sm="3" md-cols-xs="2" md-row-height-gt-sm="6:1" md-row-height="7:1" md-gutter="33px">
      <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="language in vm.languages" class="language">
          <a data-ng-click="vm.changeLanguage(language.key)"><span ng-bind="language.language | humanize"></span></a>
      </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
```

it would be great if anyone can share a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put ng-cloack as an attribute of the "md-grid-list".

```
  <md-grid-list md-cols-md="3" md-cols-lg="3" md-cols-sm="3" md-cols-xs="2" md-row-height-gt-sm="6:1" md-row-height="7:1" md-gutter="33px">
      <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="language in vm.languages" class="language">
          <a data-ng-click="vm.changeLanguage(language.key)"><span ng-bind="language.language | humanize"></span></a>
      </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you are loading your css,js dependencies could be causing this problem.

If you can move your material library dependency closer to the initial loading of the page, it may fix this. You could test this by putting jquery and material libraries inside your html head as one of your first dependencies to load. These dependencies being global to your app or just on your component can also cause this to happen. Again, you can test that with the previously mentioned approach.

I have also fixed a flavor of this problem naturally by using *ngIf in a div container wrapper around my html and that seemed to allow the dependencies for the site to load prior to showing any content. I would still try rearranging my dependencies, though.